Does the notation $u \cdot v \times w$ make sense? Why? How about the notation $u \times v \times w$?
Does the notation $u \cdot v \times w$ make sense? Why? How about the notation $u \times v \times w$?
How do I go about tackling a problem like this? There is no answer key so I have no idea what conclusion I am meant to reach. Nor do I know how to reach the conclusion that’s why I haven’t even tried anything.

you should look at the definitions.

Parentheses are missing and that is why the notations do not make sense? Is that it?

It's more than that.  In one case, there's only one sensible place to put the parentheses, so you can argue that it's obvious what the expression must mean.  In the other, there's more than one place to put them and the answer depends on the choices you make, hence the expression really doesn't make sense.  You need to say which is which and why.

I see. Further specification is needed for the second notation as it could be either interpreted as $u \times (v \times w)$ or $(u \times v) \times w$?

Well, as you remark, both of those interpretations make sense.  But that's only a problem if the two notations are in conflict.  So the question, then, is "is the vector product associative or not?"

The first one $u \cdot v \times w$ (which is explicitly $u \cdot (v \times w)$) does in general make sense since otherwise the expression is invalid. The second one can be confusing as either $(u \times v) \times w$ or $u \times (v \times w)$. You might defend that $(u \times v) \times w$ can be understood without explicit definition.
